# Efficiently position images in CSS sprites

Tags: html, css, frontend, front-end-optimization

I am trying to create a Carousel, where i will show some tweets along with the user's profile picture.

I have a created a sprite with all user's profile picture, to reduce number of network requests.

I can position the images of the sprite with `background-position`

For applying the `background-position` I can select the container-div which will hold the images either with `:nth-child` selector or I can assign a seperate id / class to each of the container for example `position-1`, `position-2` and so on.

Is there any better way apart from the above methods, by which i can efficiently position them ?

I want a CSS only solution don't want to use JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. How would we know if `nth` selectors are the best option if we don't know the HTML? Guessing is a waste of time.

Comment: nope, no other way, you have mentioned the 2 unique possibilities

Comment: mmh, there's a third one of course, it's obvious, you can assign a style attribute directly in your html tag elements `<div style='background-position:-40% -40%'>` but that's it